# delete rows in csv using python or C#?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that repeats itself like this:

```
"col1", "col2","col3"
Integer, Integer, Varchar(50)
7, 8, 21554
24, 25, 36544
"col1", "col2","col3"
Integer, Integer, Varchar(50)
7, 8, 21554
24, 25, 36544
```

How do I strip the duplicated part, including the later header, datatype row, and data rows?
I only want this:

```
"col1", "col2","col3"
Integer, Integer, Varchar(50)
7, 8, 21554
24, 25, 36544
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't even need to use the `csv` module for this.  we'll remeber what the first line of the file is and then write lines over until we see it again, at which point we'll stop, truncating the file.

```
with open('infile.csv', newline='') as infile, open('outfile.csv', 'w+',  newline='')as outfile:
     first = next(infile)
     outfile.write(first)
     for line in infile:
         if line == first:
             break
         outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you, Patrick, Your code works like charm except a minor change :remove second "with" before "open" when I ran in Python3.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this using the `csv` module (assuming Python 2.x):

```
import csv

seen = set()
with open('duplicates.csv', 'rb') as infile, open('cleaned.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in (tuple(row) for row in reader):
        if row not in seen:
            writer.writerow(row)
            seen.add(row)

print('done')
```